# How I get the error log generates from a flask app installed on CPanel?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application installed on cpanel and it's giving me some error while the application is running. Application makes an ajax request from the server, but server returns the response with a 500 error. I have no idea how I get the information that occurs to throw this error.

There's no information on the cpanel error log and is it possible to create some log file that logs errors when occur in the same application folder or something?

Answer (score 1):

When you log into cPanel go to the Errors menu and it will give a more detailed response to your errors there. You can also try and check:
 `/var/log/apache/error.log or /var/log/daemon.log`